# How to plus hex( No output)?

Tags: c++, hex, std, number-formatting

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    unsigned int  a = 0x0009, b = 0x0002;
    unsigned int  c = a + b;
    cout << c;
}
```

Now

```
c = 11
```

I want to this:

```
c = 000B
```

How can I do ?

Comment: `cout << std::hex << c`? You won't get `000` unless you specify the width and supply a filler though.

Comment: check c++ `iomanip`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't want to use ```cout```

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No. Do you have without ```cout``` edition?

Comment: @yui "_I don't want to use `cout`_" So, what is your question? The value of a number is the same, no matter with what number system you print it.

Comment: What do you want to use then? [`std::printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)?

Comment: Hex is just one possible representation of what's stored in `c`. This is starting to sound like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is the real problem you've faced with the addition you performed?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry. My English is not very good.. I want to stored in c, not ouput

Comment: It _is_ stored in `c` already. You can choose to display it in any base you want.

Comment: @yui You already have that. The value stored in `c` is 11 in decimal system, or `0xB` in hexadecimal system, or `013` in octal system, or `0b1011` in binary. These are all the same value, just represented differently.

Comment: Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Yqh75h) answer your question?

Comment: @yui.Your question is unclear, you want something else which is different from the example you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to retrieve the result in an hexadecimal specific format `XXXX`.

Computing the addition is the same as any number base, you only need to use (here I display) the result in your format.

You can do this, for instance:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


std::string displayInPersonalizedHexa(unsigned int a)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::uppercase<<  std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << std::hex<< a;
    std::string x;
    ss >>x;
    //std::cout << x;
    return x;
}
int main() {
    unsigned int  a = 0x0009, b = 0x0002;
    unsigned int  c = a + b;
    // displays 000B
    std::cout << displayInPersonalizedHexa(c) << std::endl;

    // adds c=c+1
    c=c+1;
    // displays 000C
    std::cout << displayInPersonalizedHexa(c) <<  std::endl;
    
   //0xC+5 = 0x11
    c=c+5;
    // displays 0011
    std::cout << displayInPersonalizedHexa(c) <<  std::endl;
}
```

This will output

```sh
000B
000C
0011
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to output c. I just want to store ```000B``` in ```c```, not ```11``` in ```c```

Comment: c is an unsigned int. you will have numbers in it. If you want to have `000B`, you should have another type (a string for instance) . I modified the code, now you can have a string variable containing `000B`. Does it suit?

Answer (score 3):

When you do this

```
int main() {
    unsigned int  a = 0x0009, b = 0x0002;
    unsigned int  c = a + b;
}
```

Then `c` has the value of `11`, it also has the value of `0x000B`. It also has the value of `10` in a representation that uses `11` as base.

`11` and `0x000B` (and `10`) are different representations of the same value.

When you use `std::cout` then the number is printed as decimal by default. What representation you choose to print the value on the screen has no influence whatsoever on the actual value of `c`.

Comment: I don't want to stored in decimal. I want to stored in hexdecimal

Comment: @yui It's most probably stored in binary format internally. What is the _real_ problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @yui you cannot choose how it is stored internally. Why do you want that?

Comment: @idclev463035818 My thoughts because I have to keep counting in hexadecimal.

Comment: @yui If I ask you the same question I've asked a couple of times already in a different way it may work. What makes you think it isn't stored in hexdecimal format?

Comment: @yui counting in hexadecimal is exactly the same as counting in decimal. You add `1` and the value increases by `1`. You add two numbers and the result is the sum of the two numbers. Why do you have to "keep counting in hexadecimal" ?